# how can I convert a char character representing a number, to the same number in int?

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how to convert a char number, say

```
char num = "1";
```

to the same number as an integer so

```
char num = "1"; would be converted to int numc = "1";
```

and the only way that I can think of to do it is to manually do a bunch of if statements, which seems a bit excessive, so I was just wondering if anyone knew of an easier way to do this? thanks!

Comment: int atoi ( const char * str );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, characters are really just numbers representing their character value, so:

```
char ch = '1';
int num = ch - '0';

printf("ch=%c num=%d\n", ch, num);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that in all common character sets, the character values `'0'` through `'9'` are sequentially allocated.

Notice also that `char` values are surrounded by *single* quotes, while multi-character strings are surrounded by *double* quotes.

Comment: The standard mandates that `'0'`..`'9'` are consecutive values.

Comment: That's good. I had to check [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) to make sure they were sequential there before adding that to my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! ok now this one is prob a dumb question, but with the way the character is initially created which is:

    char field_month[128];

    sscanf(field_mix, "%*[^-]-%127[^-]-", field_month);

    int num = field_month - '0';

makes gcc say that initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast, which I assumed was because int was not defined as a pointed, but that did not see to be the problem, would you by any chance know what I should do in this situation? thanks!

Comment: also sorry that the code came out like that, would not let me force separate lines

Comment: `field_month` is an *array* of characters. If you want to look at the first character in that array, use `field_month[0]`.

Comment: oh had overlooked that, and lets say for instance that the month were 10,11, or 12, would there be a way to use all characters that are located in the array? (btw this code is going to be used to take the numeric representation of a month and then convert it to human form, so for instance 1 would be jan)

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different question that what you originally posed. If you have one or more digits in an array called `field_month`, then you can convert that sequence of digits to an integer using `atoi(field_month)`.

Comment: worked great, thanks again for your help, also sorry about the confusion, have just recently started teaching myself C in order to speed up some server automation processes so not 100% with some aspects of it yet

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to your problem is to subtract '0' from your digit's value as shown below:

```
char num = '2';

int i = num - '0';
```